# pass a string which contains variables to a proc in tcl, without evaluation

Tags: tcl

I want to pass a string to a proc which contains variables, without evaluating/substituting the value of the variable for example  :

```
% set intf "blah"  
% set cmd "show router interface $intf"
% dummy_proc $cmd
```

the requirement is that, the `$cmd` that `dummy_proc` receives should be "`show router interface $intf`" and not "`show router interface blah`"

I am looking for answers which do not involve the following :

1. using a backslash for the `$` => `\$`
2. wrapping the string in curly braces `{}`

I'd appreciate any help with this. Thanks

Comment: Given (1) and (2), is this an XY problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that Tcl uniformly substitutes those bits before you procedure gets them; it's how the language is defined to operate. The sole extra piece of information you can get is this (if your version of Tcl is new enough):

```
proc example {cmd} {
    puts call=[dict get [info frame -1] cmd]
    puts cmd=$cmd
}
set intf "blah"  
set cmd "show router interface $intf"
example $cmd
```

which will print:

```
call=example $cmd
op=show router interface blah
```

The setting of `cmd` is already over and done with at the point you get to inspect.

---

The way you'd solve this with *slightly* freer requirements is:

```
proc example {cmd} {
    puts "supplied: $cmd"
    # Do the substitutions as in "double quotes" *in the caller's context*
    set cmd [uplevel 1 [list subst $cmd]]
    puts "substituted: $cmd"
}
set intf "blah"  
set cmd {show router interface $intf}
example $cmd
```

which prints:

```
supplied: show router interface $intf
substituted: show router interface blah
```

You *cannot* solve this without delaying the substitution of `$intf` until the evaluation of the procedure, and that *requires* either braces or the (ugly) strategies listed in the other answers. Tcl style genuinely encourages the use of braces for this sort of thing, and double quotes *always* mean that variables (and command calls) inside are to be substituted immediately. Delay that substitution (which you have the tools for) and you can substitute at the moment you need.

Answer (score 0):

Simple. For example, you could use one of these:

```
set cmd "show router interface \x24intf"
set cmd [format "show router interface $%s" intf]
append cmd "show router interface " $ intf
set cmd [string cat "show router interface " $ intf]
```

But I expect that isn't what you wanted either.

Tcl provides an eminently simple and expressive way to specify a minimally-substituted string:

```
set cmd {show router interface $intf}
```

This has the advantages of clarity and of not complicating the interpreter with exceptions from the straightforward evaluation rules that Tcl uses.

Documentation:
[Summary of Tcl language syntax](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/Tcl.htm)

Comment: Thanks for the Answer Peter, but as mentioned in the post, point 2 states the same approach. I'm looking for another alternative, if there exists one.

Comment: @user3624379: well, that is why I gave you four alternatives that don't use braces. Unless you have some specific reason not to use braces, it is still the best way.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ugly alternatives to using braces, for example:

```
    set cmd [string map "% $" "show router interface %intf"]
    set cmd [join [list "show router interface $" "intf"] ""]
    set cmd [format "show router interface %sintf" $]
    set cmd "show router interface [set $ $]intf"
    set cmd $; set cmd "show router interface [set cmd]intf"
    set cmd "show router interface [lindex $ 0]intf"
```

Why you would want to use these alternatives instead of braces is a mystery.